# Matlab Memory Ones(100K,100K)

Tags: matlab, memory

I want to compute reachability matrix of a network with 200,000 nodes and more than 500K links. Can Matlab handle that? I got memory error when I started

Just to give simply code as:

> ones(100000,100000)

It says Error using ones
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
How to solve memory problem? I have more than enough hard disk space for using the virtual memory but I do not now how to use it explicitly. I have set the preference to remove the limit of maximum array size. Any help?

Comment: Do you actually need a matrix that large or can you use a `sparse` matrix or different data structure instead? Also does it need to be a floating point datatype? You may be able to get away with an integer datatype.

Comment: That matrix would take up 80 GB of memory... using virtual memory is going to be very slow

Comment: Sparse matrix does not help for the first matrix would be all ones. I did increase the virtual memory by adding custom pagefile to 10GB but Matlab can only utilize less than 4.5GB additional on top of the 4GB physical RAM. Is there anyway to increase the usage of virtual memory in Matlab? If I use `ones(100000,100000,'uint8')` it requires only 10GB.